# Data Mapper Configuration is null in wso2

Tags: wso2, datamapper, wso2-enterprise-integrator, wso2-esb

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/x6kTR.png)

Data Mapper Configuration is appearing null in wso2

Answer (score 0):

You need to have a Registry Resources project created, to save the Datamapper configuration.

https://ei.docs.wso2.com/en/latest/micro-integrator/develop/create-integration-project/#integration-project
https://ei.docs.wso2.com/en/latest/micro-integrator/references/mediators/data-Mapper-Mediator/